# What is an appropriate answer to the phrase "till later"?

Tags: phrases

What is an appropriate answer to the phrase "till later"?

In my case I think I could not answer "See you", because it is a chat, so we are going to chat without using the camera.

So the only answer I could think of is "Bye", which seems to be a little bit cold.

Comment: The same as "Hasta luego".

Comment: Define "appropriate answer".

Comment: You could say "I look forward to it". But as indicated this is more of a question of social interaction as opposed to English usage per se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Farewell
- All right then
- Have a good day
- Take care
- Have a good one
- Catch you later
- See you around

Might work?

Comment: Hello, iiRosie1. ELU is aimed at linguists. This question is a poor fit for the site. Answering it merely encourages other inappropriate questions.